# Str_split is returning only half of the string

Tags: r, regex, tibble, strsplit

I have a tibble and the vectors within the tibble are character strings with a mix of English and Mandarin characters. I want to split the tibble into two, with one column returning the English, the other column returning the Mandarin. However, I had to resort to the following code in order to accomplish this:

```
    tb <- tibble(x = c("I我", "love愛", "you你")) #create tibble
en <- str_split(tb[[1]], "[^A-Za-z]+", simplify = T) #split string when R reads a character that is not a-z
ch <- str_split(tb[[1]], "[A-Za-z]+", simplify = T) #split string after R reads all the a-z characters
tb <- tb %>%
  mutate(EN = en[,1],
         CH = ch[,2]) %>%
  select(-x)#subset the matrices created above, because the matrices create a column of blank/"" values and also remove x column
tb
```

I'm guessing there's something wrong with my RegEx that's causing this to occur. Ideally, I would like to write one str_split line that would return both of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` from `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(tb$x, "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])", perl = TRUE))
```

---

Or we can use

```
library(stringr)
tb$en <- str_extract(tb$x,"[[:alpha:]]+")   
tb$ch <- str_extract(tb$x,"[^[:alpha:]]+")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_match` and get data for English and rest of the characters separately.

```
stringr::str_match(tb$x, "([A-Za-z]+)(.*)")[, -1]

#     [,1]   [,2]
#[1,] "I"    "我"
#[2,] "love" "愛"
#[3,] "you"  "你"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using `str_extract` from package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
tb$en <- str_extract(tb$x,"[A-z]+")   
tb$ch <- str_extract(tb$x,"[^A-z]")
```

In case there's more than one Chinese character, just add `+`to `[^A-z]`.

Alternatively, use `gsub`and backreference:

```
tb$en <-  gsub("(\\w+).$", "\\1", tb$x)
tb$ch <-  gsub("\\w+(.$)", "\\1", tb$x)
```

Yet another solution macthes unicode characters with `[ -~]+` and excludes them with `[^ -~]+`:

```
tb$en <-  str_extract(tb$x, "[ -~]+")
tb$ch <-  str_extract(tb$x, "[^ -~]+")
```

Result:

```
tb
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x      en    ch   
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 I我    I     我   
2 love愛 love  愛   
3 you你  you   你
```